# How to pass parameters in socket

Tags: node.js, sockets

I need to pass parameters in socket and I use the method `emit`.
Server Side:

```
var http=require('http');

var numero_giocatori=0;

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();

var vettore_clienti=[];
var chatServer = net.createServer();


chatServer.on('connection', function(client) {
    numero_giocatori=numero_giocatori+1;
    vettore_clienti.push(client);
    if(numero_giocatori===2){
        console.log("IScritto "+numero_giocatori);
        for(var i=0;i<vettore_clienti.length;i++){
            vettore_clienti[i].emit('vettore_clienti',vettore_clienti);
        }
    }
});
chatServer.listen(8000,'127.0.0.1');
```

But I don't know how read the value that I passed first with `emit` method.
Client Side:

```
var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(8000, '127.0.0.1', function() {

});

client.on('data', function(data) {
console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Are both codes NodeJS? Why did you call the second one "Client side"?

Comment: @GuiImamura: One node app has opened a socket that’s listening for connections. Programs that do this are often called “servers”. The other app connects to a host on a specific port. Such a program is commonly called a “client”. These terms are much older than web development.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert Oh, right. Thank you for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node’s TCP sockets are meant to be universal (the other end does not have to be a Node program) and do not prescribe any standards for how your messages are formatted. In other words: you’re free to create your own encoding for messages.

Or you can simply use JSON (if you don’t care about the overhead this creates when compared to an encoding that is better adapted to your specific use case):

#### Server

```
var http=require('http');

var numero_giocatori=0;

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();

var vettore_clienti=[];
var chatServer = net.createServer();

function sendMessage(client, messageType) {
    var message = {type: messageType, data: [].slice.call(arguments, 2)};
    client.write(JSON.stringify(message)); // Sending a string implicitly converts it into a buffer using utf-8
}


chatServer.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log('Got connection', client);
    numero_giocatori=numero_giocatori+1;
    vettore_clienti.push(client);
    if(numero_giocatori===2){
        console.log("IScritto "+numero_giocatori);
        for(var i=0;i<vettore_clienti.length;i++){
            sendMessage(vettore_clienti[i], 'welcome', "You are client number", i+1, 'of', vettore_clienti.length);
        }
    }
});
chatServer.listen(8000,'127.0.0.1');
```

#### Client

```
var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(8000, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    var message = JSON.parse(data.toString()); // calling toString() with no arguments assumes the buffer is in utf-8
    var messageType = message.type;
    var data = message.data;
    console.log.apply(console, data);
});
```

Note that this way you are restricted to sending stuff that can actually be represented in JSON. This excludes functions, and values like `NaN` or `Infinity`. Sending an array of clients complete with functions and streams like you tried in your sample code thus won’t work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if node.js net socket library has an emit method.

The docs suggest that sending data over the socket is done through the sockets [`write`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_write_data_encoding_callback) method.

---

socket.io would allow you to create websocket connections, and to emit and listen for arbitrary events:

http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server#emit